# Getting Samples of Clusters in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis, sample

I have a dataset in a pandas dataframe that contains a list of names and the cluster they belong to. In total there are over 1,000 different clusters. I'm looking to create 4 samples containing 100 of the clusters with no overlaps of the clusters between them. Also keep in mind that the number of names in each cluster can differ and the cluster values are not sequential. Below is a sample of how the dataset looks. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

| Name | Cluster |
| --- | --- |
| Mike Jordan | 1 |
| Michael Jordan | 1 |
| Joe Smith | 3 |
| John S. | 6 |
| John Smith | 6 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.random.choice` with `replace=False` to select the 400 non-overlapping unique clusters and then you can `array_split` to create the groups of 100 from that. There are tons of ways to then split the data, but here I'll just map a unique ID back to the original DataFrame based on the cluster and which array in the array_split it belonged to.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': list('ABCDEFGHIJ'),
                   'cluster': [1,2,3,1,2,5,5,6,6,7]})
```

#### Code

```
np.random.seed(1234)
N = 4
nsplits = 2

clusts = np.random.choice(df.cluster.unique(), size=N, replace=False)
d = {c: i for i, arr in enumerate(np.array_split(clusts, nsplits)) for c in arr}
#{3: 0, 2: 0, 7: 1, 1: 1}

df['group'] = df['cluster'].map(d).astype('Int64')
#  name  cluster  group
#0    A        1      1
#1    B        2      0
#2    C        3      0
#3    D        1      1
#4    E        2      0
#5    F        5   <NA>
#6    G        5   <NA>
#7    H        6   <NA>
#8    I        6   <NA>
#9    J        7      1
```

So clusters 2 and 3 are mapped to group 1 and clusters 1 and 7 are mapped to group 2. In your code you could use `N = 400` and `nsplits = 4` to get 4 groups of 100. And now you can `df.groupby('group')` to get the DataFrames for each of the groups we mapped back.